# SQL delete rows with same value in column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, distinct

I have column "name" with the same values.

For example:

`select * table WHERE name Like 'Kate'`

Result: 2 rows with this name.
I need leave only one row that has this name (random) in such rows. 
And don't show other entries that have the same names.
How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `DELETE FROM table  WHERE name Like 'Kate' limit 1`

Answer (score 2):

you can use limit when you delete

`DELETE FROM table  WHERE name Like 'Kate' limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from QQNAMES
  where name like 'Kate%'
  AND ID <> (select id from QQNAMES 
  where name like 'Kate%'
  and ROWNum <=1);
```

Will delete all names in 'Kate%' pattern except the first one

*Note: Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause. **MySQL** supports the **LIMIT** clause to select a limited number of records, while **Oracle** uses **ROWNUM**.* from: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that;

```
delete from table where Id IN(
select Id from table WHERE name Like 'Kate' limit 1)
```